# Pass information from popover table to a web view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm using a `ViewController` with `Button` for `PopOverView`, inside a Popover View I load a Table created only by code and never a `TableController` in my storyboard.

So I can use the pop-over, I see a Table with content get from a plist, but can't send a information from row selected to a webview in the ViewController. here the code:

My `ViewController.m` (IBAction) to spawn popover:

```
- (IBAction)popover:(id)sender {

    SAFE_ARC_RELEASE(popover); popover=nil;

    //the controller we want to present as a popover
    RADTwitterPicker *controller = [[RADTwitterPicker alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    controller.delegate = self;
    popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller];
    popover.tint = FPPopoverRedTint;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(380, 500);
    }
    else {
        popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 300);
    }
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];
}
```

Here I say to pop over to show `RADTwitterPicker.m`, my popover opens and I can choose from table, Now I am trying to send information from `PopOver` to a `WebView` in first controller:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedTableRow:)]) {

        RADViewController *detailVC = [[RADViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        detailVC.twitter = [tweetList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        [self.delegate selectedTableRow:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

And to read this in `RADViewController.m` using this method :

```
- (void)tweetView {
    [twitWidg addSubview: twitLoad];
    [twitWidg loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[twitter objectForKey:@"web"]]]];
    [twitWidg reload];
    twTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(twiterLoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self tweetView];
}

- (void)selectedTableRow:(NSUInteger)rowNum {
    NSLog(@"SELECTED ROW %d",rowNum);
    [self tweetView];
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

But when the popover is dismissed i see nothing on my `WebView`...
Any one has any idea to fix this?

thanks.

Comment: you are setting the ViewController as the delegate to popover

Comment: Yes I do but nothing happen

Comment: Is RADViewController your first view controler?  Not very clear what is going on in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  You created detailVC, assigned same data to it, and make a callback...to "first view controller"?

Comment: No your setting popover delegate to ViewController but you need the result in RADViewController hence its not working set the delegate to RADViewController then it will work

Comment: yes RADViewController is FirstViewController, and i Load inside the pop over the RADTwitterPicker. Then load content from plist file using NSMUtableArray called tweetList and pass and try to pass the information to a NSMutableDictionary in my FirstViewController called twitter.

Comment: To setting delegate on ViewController i use this /@/property (nonatomic,assign) RADTwitterPicker *delegate; and in .M /@/synthesize delegate=_delegate;

Comment: detailVC.twitter is not the same insrance as the one that you make a callback with selectedTableRow.  You need to do the getting "content from plist...tweetLst...twitter" part in the - (void)selectedTableRow:(NSUInteger)rowNum method once you got a callback with the row number.

Comment: Sorry i cant understand, can you witre a simple example? thx

Answer (score 1):

After re-read you posting, I saw that what you have missed.

Here are my suggestions to fix it:

A.  Modify your delegate to return the twitter object not indexPath.row.  Here is your new:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedTableRow:)]) {

        [self.delegate selectedTableRow:[tweetList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

Make sure you modify your delegate's declaration to reflex this. (return twitter object not the row number).

B.   And here is your new:

```
- (void)selectedTableRow:(WhateverTwitterClassIs *)twitter {

        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
       [twitWidg addSubview: twitLoad];
        [twitWidg loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[twitter objectForKey:@"web"]]]];
        [twitWidg reload];
        twTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(twiterLoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```